# setsockopt returns -1: errno is set to 0

Tags: c++, c, networking

I am novice in network programming and I have rewritten `A Simple Stream Server` from http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/clientserver.html#figure2 in `Visual Studio 2015`. Here I'm posting only the part of the code (until `freeaddrinfo(servinfo)`) as the problem already exists there.

```
// StreamServer.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <errno.h>

#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include "WinSock2.h"
#include "ws2ipdef.h"
#include "WS2tcpip.h"

#define PORT "3490" // the port users will be connecting to
#define BACKLOG 10  // how many pending connections queue will hold

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void* get_in_addr(struct sockaddr* sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main()
{
    WSAData wsaData;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int sockfd, new_fd; // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    int yes = 1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) == -1) {
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol) == -1)) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&yes, sizeof(yes)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            closesocket(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

`setsockopt(...)` fails and sets `errno` variable to `0`. I've also printed the error and it says `No error`. I don't understand what I did wrong. I thought that the program should have run and wait on the specified port until some client sends data to that port.

Comment: Windows `SO_REUSEADDR` expects the argument to be a `BOOL`, not an `int`, and I don't think any winsock functions set `errno`. They use a different function for getting error codes... `WSAGetLastError()`?

Comment: @Shawn Thank you, you're right. The example in the above link is written for Linux and because of that I was confused.

Comment: the posted code is using some C++ header files.  Please correct OR change the tag from 'c' to 'c++'

Answer (score 1):

You're kind of mixing idioms.

`perror` comes from programming on Linux (or, more broadly, POSIX-compliant systems), and will tell you what `errno` is.

But Windows doesn't use `errno`! To get the error from a Windows sockets function you'll want `WSAGetLastError()`. That should tell you what you did wrong (in this case, passing the wrong kind of argument for `SO_REUSEADDR`).